# Why is the selected row partially obscured in GWT 2.4 DataGrid?

Tags: gwt, datagrid

When scrolling down on a DataGrid page using the keyboard, the last visible item on the visible range, if it's partially obscured, does not become fully visible when it gets selected. The same seems to happen when selecting the row with the mouse. The row becomes visible enough to fully show the **Number** column value as can be seen in the screenshot, but the image stays partially obscured. The same thing happens without any footer being visible, so the footer obscuring the row does not seem to be the issue here. Also, the behaviour is identical when selecting the *first* visible item - only the **Number** value becomes fully visible.

[image: DataGrid example]

This is kind of a minor issue but since the DataGrid in my case is mostly browsed using the keyboard, it really has quite a big impact on usability. So - Any ideas what could be done to ensure full row visibility when it is selected?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, seems like the behaviour depends on which column is selected, d'oh. If I click on the image cell to focus the grid, then the scrolling works pretty much as expected. I wonder if it's possible to force the image cell to have focus regardless of which cell the focus was given to? There are some other usability things as well, like when scrolling down and the last item gets selected, the widget scrolls down so that the selected item is in the middle. I'd like to disable this kind of auto-scrolling as it feels kinda "jumpy" this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending DataGrid and overriding setKeyboardSelected(int, boolean, boolean) as follows seems to do the trick, but is of course a hack and not an optimal solution at all.

```
@Override
protected void setKeyboardSelected(int index, boolean selected, boolean stealFocus) {
    if (KeyboardSelectionPolicy.DISABLED == getKeyboardSelectionPolicy() || !isRowWithinBounds(index) || getColumnCount() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    super.setKeyboardSelected(index, selected, stealFocus);
    TableRowElement tr = getRowElement(index);
    tr.scrollIntoView();
}
```